# Virtual Box Windows 10 VM, Make VM undetectable

Tags: windows, virtualbox, virtual-machine, windows-registry

So I've made a Windows 10 virtual machine in Virtual Box. I'm trying to make it so that it can't be detected that I'm actually running a vm, mainly by just a person looking through the device manager. I'm having one problem, I can't find the registry key for the name of name of my DVD/CD-ROM drive, it's called VBOX-CD ROM. That's a dead giveaway, so if anyone could help me out this, that would be great.

Currently at Computer/HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE/SYSTEM/ControlSet001/Enum/PCI. Can only see keys that start with VEN_8086. 
I'm really new to the Windows registry so if I'm probably just doing something completly braindead.

Screenshot: 
[image]

Comment: The graphics is also a dead giveaway and so are many other virtualized devices. I don't think it's doable.

Comment: So how would someone make a vm that would be difficult to find out actually is a vm? It can't be completely impossible right?

Comment: Maybe disabling access to the device manager...

Comment: yeah that would probably work